# realurl multilanguage 404 page redirection

Tags: php, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using a  TYPO3 6.2 multilanguage installation and I want to redirect the user (using realurl extension) to a 404 page (created in the backend) in such way :

For en language (default) --> https://www.example.com/gfdg --> https://www.example.com/404

For de language --> https://www.example.com/de/gdfg --> https://www.example.com/de/404

Is it possible with $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible if you set `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageNotFound_handling']` in `/typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php`, e.g. like here suggested: https://wiki.sebkln.de/doku.php?id=typo3:404

But Typo3 6.2 is outdated, so you should update to a recent Typo3-Version and use [Typo3 Error Handling](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/ErrorHandling.html) instead.

Comment: You should not provide link-only answers. Please provide an example in your answer.